# css z-index between nested elements?

Tags: z-index, nested-lists

I need to get a nested element displayed partially behind its parent element, but so far it doesn't work.

The parent element is positioned 'relative' and has a z-index of 100;  the nested element has a z-index of 50 and is positioned 'absolute', as in the following example:

```
    <ul class="parent-element">
        <li> some text </li>
        <li> some text </li>
        <li> some text 
                <ul class="nested-element">
                    <li> some text </li>
                    <li> some text </li>
                    <li> some text </li>
                </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>

    <style type="text/css">
    .parent-element {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1000000000000000000000000;
    {

    .nested-element {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    {
</style>
```

See, no matter what z-index I give them the nested element remains on top. It suggests to me that you can't change the stack order between parent-child elements, yet it would be a very good solution here, as I need the nested list to partially slide under the parent list.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are correct that you cannot change the stacking order between a parent and its children.  I've used the `clip` property in the past to simulate a sub-list sliding under its parent by clipping away the part of the child that overlaps with (is 'under') the parent.

**EDIT** Here's an example of how I've used clip in the past to achieve the effect, but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/q4170f3o/3/

(Sorry my original example had a fixed height in there for no reason.)

Basically what it's doing is setting the right edge of the child to the right edge of the parent and clipping it to zero width but at the right edge of the child.  Then on hover, you transition the left clip boundary all the way to the left while moving the right edge of the child to the right an amount equal to the width of the child.  Unfortunately I can't think of how this would work without setting a width on the child, but I haven't found that to be an issue in practice when I've used this in navigation scenarios.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Clip sounds useful except in this case the nested list is wider than the parent list thus extends beyond its right edge, and clip can only clip to 4 corners correct?

Comment: Yes, you can only clip a rectangular region with the `clip` property, so if you wanted it to be visible on both sides of the parent that wouldn't work.  What effect are you looking for?  If it's just to have it slide out from underneath where it is only visible say, to the right of the parent, clips should still work for you even if the child is wider.  I'll grab an example of what I've used and edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I thought since clip clips a rectangle the top of the clipped child element will have a gap above it where it extends beyond the parent's width.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your question.  Can you give more info about the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Cool, ok, so the nested list is wider than the parent, so if i use clip on it, the part of it that extends outside the parent will have a gap above it (which is why i wanted t use z-index, to be able to use negative margin on the whole nested list to get it flush against the element above). Hope that's clear, if not, let me know.

Comment: The nested list in your code above is positioned absolutely, relative to `.parent-element` (remember the actual parent element of `.nested-element` is an `<li>`, not `.parent-element`), so if you want it flush against the top of the parent list, all you have to do is set the `top` property of the nested list to 0.  If you want it flush against the `<li>` above, you need to position the `.nested-list` relative to its actual parent `<li>` by setting `position:relative` on `<li>` tags. Maybe if you added some more to your code above it might be easier for me to understand.

Comment: well the code is really that simple, it's a navigation list with a relative positioned li containing a absolute positioned nested fly out list/menu. I've no problem in positioning the nested element flush against the top of the nav bar, the problem is z-index, the fly-out menu covers  up the parent nav bar. but i'd like it to be positioned behind the parent list/nav bar. This is because the fly-out menu is wider than the nav bar (parent), hence if using clip, the part that sticks out of the parent would also be clipped, leaving an empty gap above it which i don't want. thanks

Comment: seems strange that it isn't possible to use z-index on nested elements relative to each other, why they put this limit i don't know

Comment: You might be able to use z-index on the `<li>`s and set the one that contains the nested list lower than the others to achieve that, but  I'm really sorry I'm still not getting what you are looking for.  Most fly out menus that I've come across or built have some method of hiding the nested menu until its parent is hovered over, either with display:none (not recommended) or moving the nested item far off screen, or if you want it to fly out some options are clip or height/width animations.  Is the fiddle I posted in my answer anything like what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, your answers have helped me pinpoint and focus more. Btw, the fly out menu is hidden until the parent li is hovered over, but I guess that doesn't really make a difference. So I'll look at your latest suggestion of z-indexing the lis and watch how it goes, thanks.

Comment: I'll give up for now. There seems to be no way to affect the z-index of the nested element in any way relative to its parents, whether I set zindex on the li containing it or further up in its parent hierarchy, it unfortunately makes no difference. It seems that child elements are not meant to be able to stack behind parents, but it seems like it just limits overlapping design effects, imo.